# Sql query with date comparison in Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to fetch all records from table which are 15 days old. I have found a solution in MySql:

```
select * 
from dt_tb 
where dt >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY);
```

What its equivalent in SqlServer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE dt >= DATEADD(DAY,-15,GETDATE())
```

If you want the whole day without worrying about the time part:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE dt >= DATEADD(DAY,-15,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```